# Audit.EntityFrameworkCore Constructor on type 'MyDbContext' not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using **Audit.EntityFrameworkCore** nuget package for auditing :

```
public class MyDbContext  AuditDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

And the following code for adding the dbcontext to the DI:

```
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb"), sqlServerOptions =>
        {
            sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly.FullName);
        });
    });
```

When I call SaveChanges I get the following error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, DbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges(Object entity)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.AddAsync(Object entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Audit.EntityFramework.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataProvider.InsertEventAsync(Audi

Is there anything missing in my configurations?

Comment: You wouldn't get that error by calling `MyDbContext.SaveChanges` as the object is *already* constructed. What are you *actually* doing? Trying to compile your application or trying to apply migrations with `dotnet ef migrations` ? Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just parts of the message. The full text contains the exact location that threw and a call stack that shows the chain of calls that resulted in the exception

Comment: Don't expect people to know what Audit.EntityFrameworkCore is either. It's not needed to implement auditing, won't provide the same level of trust as native database audit mechanisms and ... it's very, very unstable, with a major (ie breaking) version every month.

Comment: I ran "Update-Database" and it printed migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Post the exception.

Comment: The exception I provided is the whole exception.

Comment: No it's not, it's just the `Exception.Message`. Post the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. If the exception is thrown while debugging, you can click on `Copy Details` in the exception popup to copy the entire exception

Comment: The call stack shows that the error was thrown by `Audit.EntityFramework.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataProvider.InsertEventAsync(`. That's Audit.NET itself trying to write an event to its own DbContext, not `MyDbContext`. Did you [configure the EF output provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/ad49efb71515026fd3e604c7f70f0c74b5459600/src/Audit.EntityFramework#ef-provider-configuration)?